# app engine modify xml

Tags: google-app-engine

I am writing a GWT app running on App Engine, which needs to modify a XML File serverside. As far as I know there is no way to modify a XML file in the WAR directory or any subdirectories. What other possibilities do I have to store that data? Can I use the Data Store somehow or should I look for storage space somewhere else and access it there (if so any recommendations?)?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the XML in the datastore as either a text or string property.

*Less than or equal to 500 characters in length:*

[`StringProperty`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#StringProperty)

*Greater than 500 characters in length:*

[`TextProperty`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#TextProperty)